# Sending an object through Serializable crashes

Tags: java, android, object, arraylist, serializable

I have the following method which is called in onCreate() in my second activity.

It gets an object from the first activity through Serializable and creates a list based on it, changes the object and sends it back to the first activity.

This works fine, but if I send back to the first activity the **unchanged** object it crashes when trying to create the list in the second activity.

```
private void createLectureListView() {

    ListView lecListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lectureListView);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    mod = (Module)i.getSerializableExtra("moduleObject");

    lectureList = new ArrayList<Lecture>();

    if (mod.lectureArrayList!=null) lectureList=mod.lectureArrayList;

    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Lecture>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lectureList);

    lecListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}
```

This is the exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

[EDIT] Also added the other bits. This is the one in Activity1:

```
private void registerClickCallback() {
    ListView listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, LectureNotes.class);
            //pass the module object we are selecting
            myIntent.putExtra("moduleObject",modulesInfo.get(position));
            pos = position;

            startActivityForResult(myIntent,1);
        }
    });
}
```

The onActivityResult method in the first ACtivity.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            mod = (Module)data.getSerializableExtra("moduleObject");
            if (mod!=modulesInfo.get(pos))
                modulesInfo.set(pos,mod);
        }
    }
}
```

[EDIT2] The stack trace

```
12-12 08:56:37.041    4143-4143/com.example.learnorizeapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.learnorizeapp/com.example.learnorizeapp.LectureNotes}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.learnorizeapp.LectureNotes.createLectureListView(LectureNotes.java:59)
            at com.example.learnorizeapp.LectureNotes.onCreate(LectureNotes.java:28)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-12 08:56:37.057      459-709/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity com.example.learnorizeapp/.LectureNotes
12-12 08:56:37.057      459-709/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity com.example.learnorizeapp/.MenuActivity
```

Comment: "crashes" suggests there's probably an exception in your log - so find it, and see whether that explains it. If you still don't know what's wrong, edit the question to include the exception.

Comment: There's something missing in your description: Act1 sends object to Act2 via intent, then Act2 sends unchanged object back to Act1, and "it crashes when trying to create the list in the second activity". At this point though, you should be back in Act1. Please clarify which activity crashes and where, and how do you call each of them: is it via startActivity() or startActivityForResult()?

Comment: @Melquiades when I click again on an item in the Act1 listview to open ACt2 again it stops. I assumed it's because it cannot create the listview in Act 2 again. using startActivityForResult(), I've copied the code in the question.

Comment: @JonSkeet Found the exception Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Right. So do you now know how to fix it? If not, we'll need more information again - the full stack trace, not just the class.

Comment: What is the full stacktrace of the NullPointerException>

Comment: @JonSkeet nope still don't know. sorry im kinda new to this. I have added the full stack trace, I think :)

Comment: This is beautiful: the lowest-rep user being helped by the highest-rep user. This is why I love stackoverflow.

Comment: Right, so which is line 59 in LectureNotes.java?

Comment: listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Lecture>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lectureList); the one in the first method i've copied :D

Comment: @JonSkeet any new ideas? do you know why the adapter wouldn't like it?

Comment: @user3076606: That would suggest that it's `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` which is throwing the exception. It would be worth checking that by extracting it out into a line on its own.

Comment: @JonSkeet How do you mean by extracting it out into a line on its own?

Comment: @user3076606: I mean have a local variable of the relevant type, initialized to `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` - then you can log the value before calling the `ArrayAdapter` constructor, and you may find that just the line initializing the variable fails.

Comment: @JonSkeet fixed it man thanks. There was a problem with _lectureList_ It was null when doing some different scenarios. :D cheers for all the help :D

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with lectureList It was returning null when doing some different scenarios like clicking on a button but not clicking on the other.